# keydown event is not working for input type search in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, keydown

I want to invoke keydown event for input type search in jquery mobile. Below is my html code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("#search1").keydown(function() {
        alert("keydown");           
        $("#search1").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
    $("#search1").keyup(function() {
        alert("keyup");
        $("#search1").css("background-color", "pink");
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="content">
<input type="search" id="search1">
<input type="text" id="text1">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

keydown event is getting fired for all the other input types, except for search type. Can someone please help on this?

Comment: Your example works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Jpa78/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `docs` found this: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

`Important: Use $(document).on('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()`

```
$(document).on( 'pageinit',function(event){
    $("#search1").keydown(function() {
        alert("keydown");           
        $("#search1").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
    $("#search1").keyup(function() {
        alert("keyup");
        $("#search1").css("background-color", "pink");
    });
});
```

Tryout this and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi Jai, its working fine with pageinit function, but not with document.ready. and

Comment: Is there any way to get the entered search query string in jquery script?

Comment: try to use jquery for this: `var iVal = $("#search1").val(); alert(iVal);`

Comment: Hi I have tried this way, but it gives one character less than what we have entered. Eg: if we enter "hai", in alert its giving only "ha"

Comment: We need to write it in keyup, not in keydown. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

### Include jQuery Mobile file

What you need to do is just include a jQuery file into your project. A file named jQuery.mobile.js or quite similar (ex. jQuery.ui.js) of any version can help you.

You can download it from : [jQuery Mobile Official | Download](https://jquerymobile.com/download/)
I suggest to use

> ResolveClientUrl

while giving path.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working check here: JS Fiddle

[**FIDDLE'd**](http://jsfiddle.net/RFu3b/)

```
:)
```

Comment: Thank you Sandeep, its working fine in jsFiddle :) , but not in Chrome :(