# Text only textbox for desktop browser and mobile browser using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working in Asp.net MVC project where I have several textboxes that only accepts text and other keys like backspace,arrows etc.
My code is working fine in desktop browser but it always returns 229 for **event.keycode** in mobile browser.

```js
var AllowedKeys = [46, 8, 9, 37, 39];

$(".textonly").keydown(function (event) {
   if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, AllowedKeys) !== -1) {}
   else 
        {
           if (event.keyCode < 65 || event.keyCode > 90) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                }
        }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' name='FirstName1' placeholder = "First Name*" class = "textonly">
```

It is not working in Mobile browser.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14625553/1784876) thread will help you.

Comment: Try use event.which instead event.keyCode

Comment: It'll be probably easier if you fire a function on change that uses a regular expression to check if the text in the textbox is not text

Comment: event.which will not work. I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution that worked for both in desktop browser and mobile browser.I did not get the desired result using regular expression. I used the keycode but in a different way. Here is the code.

```
$(".textonly").keyup(function (event) {

    var AllowedKeys = [46, 8, 9, 37, 39, 189];
    var textarea = this;

    var kc = event.which || event.keyCode;

    if (!kc || kc == 229) {
        var ss = textarea.selectionStart - 1;
        var ssv = ss || 0;
        var char = textarea.value.substr(ssv, 1);
        var newchar = char.toUpperCase();         
        kc = newchar.charCodeAt(0);
    }

    if ($.inArray(kc, AllowedKeys) !== -1) {}
    else {
        if (kc < 65 || kc > 90) {
            var inputString = $(this).val();
            var shortenedString = inputString.substr(0, (inputString.length - 1));
            $(this).val(shortenedString);             
        }
    }
});
```